# securely run linux command line app from asp.net mvc app under mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, shell, command-line, mono

We have an internal and external facing asp.net mvc app running under mono on ubuntu 10.04 LTS. There is also a complicated (native, not mono) command line app that users use on the same server.  They log on via ssh to do this. We have the security for the ssh users pretty locked down, so they can't do very much other than run the command line app.

The users of these apps have to:

1. login via ssh to the server, run the command line app with whatever command line switches are required which then does some long running processing and puts a report in the db of the web app.
2. Login to the web app, then set some options for publishing a report via the web app.

The users of the apps want to skip step 1 and do it all in the web app. I am thinking of creating a service that regulary polls the db for command line app jobs to run. The jobs would be created by the users as desired in the web app.

The problem is, the users want a box in the web app where they can just fill in any command line options. But I don't want them to do something like this:

`-a dothis -b dothis & rm importantfile.txt`

...in case the user's credentials to the web app are somehow compromised. I want to make sure that only that command line app can be used and nothing else. I am thinking of preventing the characters `! | < > & / \ $ ( )` from being allowed, which looks like are not required by the command line app.

Is that good enough? Are there any other shell tricks I should know about? Should I take a different approach?

I really don't want to have to write some sort of parser for the arguments that the users supply, because there are a ton of them that the users like to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Instead of running the command line as a shell command (launching the shell to launch the program), can you launch the program itself as a new process? I believe that's what the answer here is doing: [Execute a command line utility in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817777/execute-a-command-line-utility-in-asp-net) . If the actual program is launched as a process, rather than a shell, then things like & or rm will just be arguments to the command line utility, which should be fine if the command line utility checks for bad inputs.
2. If that's not feasible (although it's probably the better option), replacing all single quotes with single quote escape sequences, then placing single quotes around each of the arguments (split the string with a space as the delimeter), could provide a similar effect. Instead of making sure you avoid all possible bad characters (; can be used similarly to & in many shells), you only need to make sure that the provided arguments can't escape out of the single quotes. (You might also want to check for single quote surrounded arguments beforehand, to avoid double quoting them, and don't cound escaped spaces when splitting up arguments, etc., so that the users can provide arguments that need spaces).

Comment: Oh yeah. I feel a bit stupid now :) I can definitely launch it as a process. I can't believe I didn't think of that earlier...